# timing constraint for bus synchronizer circuits

Tags: fpga, clock, timing, sdc

I've a bus synchronizer circuit for passing a wide register across clock domains.

I'll provide a simplified description, omitting asynchronous reset logic.

The data is generated on one clock.  Updates are many (at least a dozen) clock edges apart:

```
PROCESS (src_clk)
BEGIN
   IF RISING_EDGE(clock) THEN
      IF computation_done THEN
          data <= computation;
          ready_spin <= NOT ready_spin;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

The control signal for fresh data, which is NRZI encoded (so a valid word on the bus corresponds to a transition on the control signal).  The control signal passes through a DFF chain acting as a synchronizer.

```
PROCESS (dest_clk)
BEGIN
   IF RISING_EDGE(dest_clk) THEN
      ready_spin_q3 <= ready_spin_q2;
      ready_spin_q2 <= ready_spin_q1;
      ready_spin_q1 <= ready_spin;
   END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

The synchronizer circuit introduces a short delay, which provides plenty of time for the data bus to stabilize; the data bus is sampled directly without a risk of metastability:

```
PROCESS (dest_clk)
BEGIN
   IF RISING_EDGE(dest_clk) THEN
      IF ready_spin_q3 /= ready_spin_q2 THEN
         rx_data <= data;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

This compiles, and works well when synthesized into a Cyclone II FPGA.  However, TimeQuest reports setup and hold time violations, because it doesn't recognize the synchronizer.  Worse, the Quartus manual says

> Focus on improving the paths that show the worst slack. The Fitter works hardest on 
>   paths with the worst slack. If you fix these paths, the Fitter might be able to improve 
>   the other failing timing paths in the design.

So I want to add the right timing constraints to my project so that Quartus will spend its Fitter effort on other areas of the design.

I'm pretty sure that `set_multicycle_path` is the proper SDC (Synopsis Design Constraint) command, since the data lines will have multiple cycles of the destination clock to stabilize, but I can't find any complete examples using this command to describe clock domain crossing logic.

I'd really appreciate some guidance on writing SDC timing constraints for synchronizers.  If you see a problem with this approach, please also let me know that.

---

Clock detail:

External clock generator: Two channels, refclk = 20 MHz, refclk2 = refclk/2 (10 MHz, and related).

Altera PLL: src_clk = refclk * 9/5 = 36 MHz

Altera PLL: dest_clk = refclk2 * 10 = 100 MHz

I also have data going the other direction, with 100 MHz src_clk and 36 MHz dest_clk.

---

TL;DR: What are the correct SDC timing constraints for the above code?

Comment: This would be better on the [proposed FPGA Design site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20632/programmable-logic-and-fpga-design) but that proposal hasn't reached beta yet.

Comment: Can you post the clock definitions for src_clk and dest_clk? Are they related in any way (synchronous multiples)? If they're unrelated clocks then it's typical to use set_false_path in this situation.

Comment: @Andy: I added some of the details.  Thanks for helping with this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have experience with Quartus, so treat this as general advice.

When working on paths between clock domains, timing tools expand the clocks to the least common multiple of their periods and select the closest pair of edges.

For paths from a 36 MHz clock (27.777 ns) to a 100 MHz clock (10 ns), if I did my quick calculations correctly, the closest pair of rising edges is 138.888 ns on the source clock and 140 ns on the destination clock. That's effectively a 900 MHz constraint for those paths! Depending on rounding (or for clocks with no relationship), it could come out worse than that.

There are at least three ways to write constraints for this structure. I am going to call the clocks `fast_clk` and `slow_clk` as I think that's clearer for illustration.

**Option 1: disable timing with `set_false_path`**

The easiest solution is to use `set_false_path` to disable timing between the clocks:

```
set_false_path -from [get_clocks fast_clk] -to [get_clocks slow_clk]
set_false_path -from [get_clocks slow_clk] -to [get_clocks fast_clk]
```

This is not strictly correct, since there are timing requirements for the synchronizer to work correctly. If the physical implementation delays the data too much relative to the control signal, then the synchronizer will not work. However, since there isn't any logic on the path, it's unlikely that the timing constraint will be violated. `set_false_path` is commonly used for this kind of structure, even in ASICs, where the effort vs. risk tradeoff for low-probability failures is more cautious than for FPGAs.

**Option 2: relax the constraint with `set_multicycle_path`**

You can allow additional time for certain paths with `set_multicycle_path`. It is more common to use multicycle paths with closely related clocks (e.g. interacting 1X and 2X clocks), but it will work here if the tool supports it sufficiently.

```
set_multicycle_path 2 -from [get_clocks slow_clk] -to [get_clocks fast_clk] -end -setup
set_multicycle_path 1 -from [get_clocks slow_clk] -to [get_clocks fast_clk] -end -hold
```

The default edge relationship for setup is single cycle, i.e. `set_multicycle_path 1`. These commands allow one more cycle of the endpoint clock (`-end`) for setup paths. The `-hold` adjustment with a number one less than the setup constraint is almost always needed when setting multi cycle paths, for more see below.

To constrain paths in the other direction similarly (relaxing the constraint by one period of the faster clock), change `-end` to `-start`:

```
set_multicycle_path 2 -from [get_clocks fast_clk] -to [get_clocks slow_clk] -start -setup
set_multicycle_path 1 -from [get_clocks fast_clk] -to [get_clocks slow_clk] -start -hold
```

**Option 3: specify requirement directly with `set_max_delay`**

This is similar to the effect of `set_multicycle_path` but saves having to think through the edge relationships and the effect on hold constraints.

```
set_max_delay 10 -from [get_clocks fast_clk] -to [get_clocks slow_clk]
set_max_delay 10 -from [get_clocks slow_clk] -to [get_clocks fast_clk]
```

You may want to pair this with `set_min_delay` for hold checks, or leave the default hold check in place. You may also be able to do `set_false_path -hold` to disable hold checks, if your tool supports it.

---

**Gory details of edge selection for multi-cycle paths**

To understand the hold adjustment that gets paired with each setup adjustment, consider this simple example with a 3:2 relationship. Each digit represents a rising clock edge:

```
1     2     3
4   5   6   7
```

The default setup check uses edges 2 and 6. The default hold check uses edges 1 and 4.

Applying a multi-cycle constraint of 2 with `-end` adjusts the default setup and hold checks to use the next edge after what they were originally using, meaning the setup check now uses edges 2 and 7 and the hold check uses edges 1 and 5. For two clocks at the same frequency, this adjustment makes sense — each data launch corresponds with one data capture, and if the capture edge is moved out by one, the hold check should also move out by one. This kind of constraint might make sense for two branches of a single clock if one of the branches has a large delay. However, for the situation here, a hold check using edges 1 and 5 isn't desirable, since the only way to fix it is to add an entire clock cycle of delay on the path.

The multi-cycle hold constraint of 1 (for hold, the default is 0) adjusts the edge of the destination clock uesd for hold checks backwards by one edge. The combination of 2-cycle setup MCP and 1-cycle hold MCP constraints will result in a setup check using edges 2 and 7, and a hold check using edges 1 and 4.

Comment: This answer is excellent.  I will add a tip.  Use TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to create new rules  for your sdc file.  It can be difficult to get the syntax correct if you just follow the sdc manual.  Also:  I highly recommend reading this paper:  https://fpgawiki.intel.com/wiki/File:TimeQuest_User_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer for Altera, but in Xilinx Land you can set the time delay from one clock domain to the next.  You'll have to work out the math (it is design dependent), but it is usually the shortest of the two clock periods.  Think of this time as the maximum skew between any two signals (including your control signal), and you can work out if your sync circuit is going to be able to deal with it.

set_mulicycle_path isn't the correct thing to use because that would normally deal with cases when both the source and destination are on the same clock domain.  Again, I am basing that off of my Xilinx experience so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that while you may know that the bus signals aren't going to change anywhere near the point where they're latched, the software doesn't know that.  Your best bet is to probably tell the software explicitly that the incoming bus signals are synchronized with the bus clock, and disable any optimizations in advance of the place where you actually latch them (an optimizer could theoretically replace your circuit with one that would be equivalent if the inputs really were synchronous, but which could be thrown for a loop if they change on clock cycles that the circuit you drew wouldn't care about).

Comment: Wouldn't `set_multicycle_path` be the way to tell the synthesizer/timing analyzer how often the source signals can change?  And I'm not sure what you mean by "bus clock", there's a signal bus here crossing clock domains, so which clock are you calling the "bus clock"?  I think you're right that there still could be metastability if the synthesizer introduces glitches during periods when I'm not updating `data`.  I guess I could specifically instantiate DFF blocks there :(

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think "set_multicycle_path" is more often used to tell the timing validator that a chain of combinatorial logic between two latching points should be allowed to take N(Tc)-Ts-Tp (N times cycle time minus sample time minus latch propagation time) instead of just Tc-Ts-Th.  I don't know how such a thing would interact with latching by different clocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safe to put a set_false_path over the synchronizer.

Also you could put "set_global_assignment -name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION AUTO" in the qsf to help Quartus spot the synchronizer.

Comment: What would that look like?  `set_false_path -from ready_spin -to ready_spin_q2`?  And `set_false_path -from data -to rx_data`?

Comment: `set_false_path -from src_clk -to ready_spin`
I am not sure it is appropriate to put the false path on data since you are not synchronizing it.